# Can you reference a dictionary as it is being created by list comprehension?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary

I'm trying to populate a dictionary from a pandas dataframe using list comprehension. My issue is that I need to add data to existing keys instead of overwriting them.

```
def Load_Dataframes(cursor):
    negativeitems = Load_NegativeOnhand(cursor)
    materiallog = Load_Materiallog(cursor)
    negativetrans = Join_Dataframes(negativeitems, materiallog) 
    datadict = {}
    datadict = {row[0]:Calculate_Transaction_History(row, datadict) for row in negativetrans[['item-no', 'tran-date', 'tran-time',
                                                                                       'on-hand', 'quantity', 'whse',
                                                                                        'order-no']].values}

def Calculate_Transaction_History(row, datadict):
        if not row[0] in datadict.keys():
            data = Shortage_Data.ShortageData()
            data.addrow(row)
        else:
            data = datadict[row[0]].addtransactions(row)

        return data
```

This populates the dictionary but the parameter datadict is the empty dictionary so the if statement is useless. Is it feasible to do this using list comprehension or should I just use itertuples()?

starting dataframe:

```
item-no on-hand quantity
item1   -10     2
item1   -10     4
item1   -10     10
item2   -5      1
item2   -5      1
item3   -3      2
```

end goal a dictionary with key:item-no value:class object

```
keys   data.on-hand  data.quantity
item1  -10           16
item2  -5            2
item3  -3            2
```

Grouping will not work here, it does in this example but not in what I'm fully trying to accomplish.

Comment: Can you add a small sample dataframe and the desired output that corresponds to it?  And take away all the code which isn't relevant for the problem at hand?  If you do, it'll be much easier for people to give you a useful answer.

Comment: The assignment won't happen until after the comprehension completes. As a result, you _can_ reference it within the comprehension, but it will hold whatever value/state it existed as before the comprehension ran (so empty in your case).

Comment: To your last statement, I don't know what `itertuples()` is/are, but if you use a regular for loop, instead of a comprehension, your dictionary will be incrementally built up through the loop (data from the previous iteration will be present on the following iteration).

Comment: @b_c it just iterates over dataframe rows as a named tuple. I was trying to avoid it because my actual dataframe is a material transaction ledger and is enormous, I was attempting to speed it up using list comprehension but I can't think of how to bypass this issue. And using grouping will not work, I can't actually just sum certain columns there is other criteria that isn't really important to the question.